# Перевести строку PHP виджета для WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем здравствуйте. Есть виджет для WP+BuddyPress выводящий количество обновлений пользователя (ЛС, предложения дружбы и т.д.). Но я никак не могу перевести одну строчку кода:

```
if($instance['show_count'])
printf(__('Есть %d уведомление','bpdnw'),$count);
if($instance['show_list'])
self::print_list($notifications,$count);
```

Вместо $notifications выводится "You have (количество сообщений) new message", как перевести это на родной русский язык? Спустя некоторые время до меня дошло, что возможно, эта строка берётся из системы, в таком случае можно ли как-то использовать всё это? В общем не мне вам объяснять. :)
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если так ?

```
if($instance['show_count'])
printf(__('Есть %d уведомление','bpdnw'),$count);
if($instance['show_list'])
self::print_list(__($notifications, $count),$count);
```

Ну и уже перевод соответсвенно для "системного" предложения

Comment: Код скорее всего не рабочий, но как направление идеи, думаю вполне.. ;)

Comment: Я с PHP вообще не дружу, поэтому многое непонятно. То, что вы предложили работает, но вот как же всё таки перевести?! Понятно, что %d использовать не получится, т.к. это сумма всех значений. Может в каких-то файлах самого движка это написано, и просто нужно там перевести? Потому что не может же это словосочетание браться из воздуха.